If $A,B$ are real, symmetric matrix such that $A-B$ is positive definite, is it true that $\lambda_k(A)>\lambda_k(B)$?
For a symmetric matrix $S\in M_n(\mathbb{R}),$ it's well known that all the eigenvalues of $S$ are real. We define $\lambda_k(S)$ to be the $k$-th eigenvalue of $S$ if we arrange the eigenvalues of $S$ in descending order, to be more precise: if $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $S,$ then $\lambda_k(S)=\lambda_k.$
Now my question is: if $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ are two symmetric matrix such that $A-B$ is positively definite, then is it true that $\lambda_k(A)\geq\lambda_k(B)$ (or even $\lambda_k(A)>\lambda_k(B)$) for any $1\leq k\leq n$? This is clearly true when $A,B$ can be simultaneously diagonalized using orthogonal matrix, what about the general case? Any help is appreciated!

Maybe I figure it out: Let's use the min-max theorem. For $x\in\mathbb{R}^n,$ define
$$R_A(x)=\frac{\left\langle Ax,x\right\rangle}{\left\langle x,x\right\rangle}$$
the min-max theorem says that
$$\lambda_k(A)=\min\{\max\{R_A(x):x\in U, x\ne0\}:\dim(U)=k\}$$
so if $A-B$ is positively definite, then $R_{A}(x)-R_B(x)=R_{A-B}(x)>0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n,$ thus $\lambda_k(A)>\lambda_k(B)$ for each $k.$
